# I can't plot 2 routes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I am following  this tutorial https://github.com/hiepxuan2008/GoogleMapDirectionSimple/ I cloned and tried to run it, it works perfectly but when I created my own project just exactly from the tutorial it won't work.

Does someone experienced this? please help.

Comment: please explain better what you mean for "it won't work"... crash, errors... and post your code

Comment: it won't plot the polyline

Comment: Like N Dorigatti said, please post the code in where you plot the polyline. Also, if you get any error message, please include that as well.